# Advanced Custom Fields get sub field image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a sub field in ACF, named 'imgcolumn_1'.

This is set to be an image, and allows the user to add an image.

Now, when in PHP, I am trying to retrieve the input the user adds.

For example, I have another sub field in AFC called column_1, which I retrieve using

```
<?php the_sub_field('column_1');?>
```

Is there another way to retrieve the image? I am trying the below:

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('imgcolumn_1'); ?>" />
```

But this doesnt display the image, but instead shows the following:

[image: current image]

When I inspect this, I can see the URL is there, but it is surrounded by other numbers?

[image: current inspect element]

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you return a **URL** an **Array** or an **ID** from your field?

looks like an **array** to me so: 
Solution 1:

```
$image = get_sub_field('imgcolumn_1');
<img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" />
```

Solution 2 (if **id**):

```
$image = get_sub_field('imgcolumn_1');
<img src="<?php echo get_permalink($image);?>" />
```

Solution 3 (if **url**):

```
$image = get_sub_field('imgcolumn_1');
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get URL of Image by `get_sub_field('imgcolumn_1')['url'];`

As function `get_sub_field()` returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I needed to select 'image_url' as the return type!

Comment: exactly what i thought :)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to set the ACF contents image sub field return format to 'Image ID'. As seen in the following screenshot.

[image: image id in acf options]