# Advanced Custom Fields the_sub_field()['url'] but it doesn't return the URL

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

this is a follow up to this question [advanced custom fields can't do nested loops repeater inside repeater have_rows() not doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566543/advanced-custom-fields-cant-do-nested-loops-repeater-inside-repeater-have-rows)

Now I'm stuck on a problem where I can't get the sub field URL.

```
          <div class="tc__agenda-speaker">
              <?php while (have_rows('agenda_event_speakers')) : the_row(); ?>
              <div class="tc__agenda-speaker-headshot">
                  <!-- DEBUG LINE -->
                  <div style="color: red;"><?php echo the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['src'] ?></div>
                  <img src="<?php the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['url'] ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['alt'] ?>">
              </div>
              <div class="tc__agenda-speaker-info">
                  <h4><?php the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_name') ?></h4>
                  <p><?php the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_title') ?></p>
              </div>
              <?php endwhile ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif ?>
```

This line

`<?php the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['url'] ?>`

It's output is this

```
16835, 16835, Name color 2, Name-color-2.png, 152744, http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Name-color-2.png, http://website.com/post/post-title-here/Name-color-2/, , 86, , , Name-color-2, inherit, 16799, 2021-02-02 16:45:53, 2021-02-02 16:45:53, 0, image/png, image, png, http://website.com/wp-includes/images/media/default.png, 500, 500, Array
```

The fields returns format is array

[image]

[Advanced Custom Fields get sub field image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922189/advanced-custom-fields-get-sub-field-image/29922394)

> You can use get URL of Image by get_sub_field('imgcolumn_1')['url'];
>
> As function get_sub_field() returns an array.

this documentation https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/ indicates there's no difference in accessing indexes

It does say

> This function is essentially the same as echo get_sub_field()

If I go

`<?php echo the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['url'] ?>`

the img src is `unknown`

How do you access url index of image array in a sub field in advanced custom fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple - i had no image set in the field in the first place...

This is in fact the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

"Essentially the same" and "The same" is where you're getting tripped up. One of the places where `the_sub_field()` and `get_sub_field()` are different is when you are dealing with values that cannot be directly converted to a string.

To answer your immediate question; you need to do exactly what you talk about in the question, namely change:

```
<?php the_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['url']?>
```

To

```
<?php echo get_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['url']?>
```

The reason for this is that `the_sub_field()` does not return a value it `echo`es the value so there is no array with a property `url` for you to access. What your original code is doing is essentially the same as

```
$variable = null;
$variable['url'];
```

Which isn't what you want.

The reason that you're getting `unknown` is that `the_sub_field()` does *attempt* to output something; but because this particular subfield is more complex it doesn't work how you expect. Inside that function something like this is happening:

```
$subfieldValue = array();
echo $subfieldValue;
return;
```

I expect that if one were to look under the hood of `the_sub_field()` you would see something essentially like this:

```
function the_sub_field($key){
    $value = get_sub_field($key);
    echo $value;
    return;
}
```

Comment: sorry `<?php echo get_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot')['url']?>
` doesn;'t work...

Comment: can you do `<?php var_dump(get_sub_field('agenda_event_speaker_headshot'))?>` and post the result

Comment: `/Users/kawnah/Sites/www.website.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/template-name.php:443:boolean false`

Comment: that means that the field is not set on the post and/or row that you are on

Comment: each row is a different type is that the problem?